# edit string in multi thread

Tags: c++, string

I am newer for c++, and I know in c++0x multithreading support is poor.
But now I have to edit a string val in multi thread, I use thread_mutex to protect the val. The problem is the program always core dump when runing.

Although after re-design I find a better solution but I can't figure out why it core. So could some one told me about what happend?
The code is like below

```
using namespace std;
const static int kThreadSize = 48; 
map<string, string> gMap;
string gStr = ""; 
void * func(void * data)
{
    while(true)
    {   
        printf("%s\n", gStr.c_str());
        pthread_mutex_t m;
        pthread_mutex_init(&m, NULL);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&m);

        gStr = gStr + "a";//core in this line
        printf("%x\n", &gStr);//print the address

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
        pthread_mutex_destroy(&m);

        printf("%s\n", gStr.c_str());
    }   
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t threads[kThreadSize]; 
    for(int i = 0; i < kThreadSize; i ++) 
    {   
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, &func, &gMap);
    }   
    for(int i = 0; i < kThreadSize; i ++) 
    {   
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

---

EDIT:
By using the global mutex will solve the problem pointed by Mike.Here I don't paste the new source code.

My new question is I also can't understand why it will core when edit a string in multithreading. Because of COW or reference count?

Comment: If you are just learning c++, then maybe you should better stay away from manual multithreading. Main problem I see with your program is that all threeads need to use the same mutex instead of one each. But even after you correct that, your program will most likely not run any faster than a single threaded version.

Comment: OMG. It's my fault. When I edit the program use the global mutex, it seems run correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As i can see there is a problem with yours Mutex, because it is create into the method `func()` and it make that each thread invocation of `func()`create a new mutex, it is happened by each threat that invokes this method.

As MikeB says, i sugest you review the thread theory but, meanwhile, try to use a unique mutex to synchronize the access to `gMap`, as the example shows:

```
using namespace std;

const static int kThreadSize = 48; 
map<string, string> gMap;
string gStr = ""; 

pthread_mutex_t m;

void * func(void * data)
{
    while(true)
    {   
        printf("%s\n", gStr.c_str());
        pthread_mutex_lock(&m);

        gStr = gStr + "a";//core in this line
        printf("%x\n", &gStr);//print the address

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);

        printf("%s\n", gStr.c_str());
    }   
}

int main()
{
    pthread_mutex_init(&m, NULL);

    pthread_t threads[kThreadSize]; 
    for(int i = 0; i < kThreadSize; i ++) 
    {   
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, &func, &gMap);
    }   
    for(int i = 0; i < kThreadSize; i ++) 
    {   
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: yes, I have rewrite my code like yours and it won‘t core again.